# Putting data from SONObjectWithData to UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i am building a app in which i am getting data from a php file and already NSLoging it in xcode and it is showing data in this format:

```
jsonObject=(
        (
        1,
        abc,
        "abc@xyz.com",
        "501 B3 Town"
    ),
        (
        2,
        sam,
        "sam@xyz.com",
        "502 B3 Town"
    ),
        (
        3,
        jhon,
        "jhon@xyz.com",
        "503 B Town"
    )
)
```

and here is my viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    statuses=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url/result.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Finished with status code: %i", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
         id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
         NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@",jsonObject);
          statuses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 }];
```

}

now i want to display all records in uitableview. can anyone tell me how can i do that. Thanks

Comment: do you know how to create `UITableView` ?

Comment: yupi do know that but how can i load that data in to a uitableview that is my question. thanks

Comment: Create a model NSObject Model class, and display by using this model itself.

Comment: Can you please share your json response data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this tutorial out:
http://thedarkdev.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/web-service-apps-in-ios7-json-with.html

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return myObject.count;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
    UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSMutableString *text;
//text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:title]];
text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
       [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:title]];

NSMutableString *detail;
detail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@ ",
         [tmpDict objectForKey:author]];

NSMutableString *images;
images = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
         [tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];


cell.textLabel.text = text;
cell.detailTextLabel.text= detail;
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 70);
cell.imageView.image =img;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I This format is  Array -> Array format in inner array may count is consistent  (4) elements

Try This onece

No of row in Sections method take - jsonparsingarray count

Cell for row at index method

display like this ex: name and email id that index is 1 & 3

```
if ([[jsonparsingarray objectatindex:indexpath.row] count])
{
 cell.textlable.text     = [[jsonparsingarray objectatindex:indexpath.row]objectatindex:1];
 cell.detailtextlable.text = [[jsonparsingarray objectatindex:indexpath.row]objectatindex:3];

}
```